# How to make a projectile instantiate in the direction of the cursor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a bullet hell game for fun and to work on my Unity and C# code writing skills. I'm currently having an issue with Instantiating a projectile, and instantiating that object at a certain rotation and velocity. The rotation of the projectile I want to face the cursor, and the velocity is fixed. My code is as shown:

```
    Vector3 sp = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
    Vector3 dir = (Input.mousePosition - sp).normalized;
    Instantiate (projectile, sp);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce (dir * 500);
```

I know it's wrong in the fact that my *Instantiate* function is written incorrectly, but I'm struggling in figuring out how to correctly write the *Instantiate* function and how to make the projectile face the cursor in terms of rotation.

Thanks a ton for your help, if you need any more information, just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a couple of things: set the `forward` vector or set the rotation using `Quaternion.LookRotation()` on the instantiated object.

```
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    //bullet.transform.forward = dir;            
    bullet.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);

    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(dir * 500);
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that you need to keep track of all your bullets especially if you plan to instantiate a lot of them. Look into [object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling).